# Como criar um popup com um dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Como faço para criar um popup com um `DROPDOWNLIST` em `Asp.net C#` "MVC" ou `Javascript/Jquery` ?

Da para chamar esse popup através de um `ActionLink` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8065042/2912399

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V0pr0A

Comment: @TobyMosque, eu consigo fazer isso ao clicar numa ActionLink ?

Comment: @bigown sabe essa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos exemplos abaixo irei utilizar o Zurb Foundation para abrir um Modal:

Caso queira abrir um Popup com um conteudo que já exista na pagina, não tem pq usar um `ActionLink`, então o melhor seria fazer com uma tag `<a href="#" />`

**Model**

```
using System;
namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Opcao
    {       
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var opcoes = new List<Opcao>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
            {
                opcoes.Add(new Opcao { 
                    ID = i, 
                    Descricao = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                });
            }
            return View(opcoes);
        }

    }
}
```

**View Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleApp.Opcao>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal">Abrir PopUp</a>
            <div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
                <p>
                    @Html.Label("Opcoes", "Opcoes")
                    @Html.DropDownList("Opcoes", Model.Select(item => new SelectListItem {
                        Value = item.ID.ToString(),
                        Text  = item.Descricao
                    }))
                </p>
                <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">×</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(function () {
                $(document).foundation();       
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Agora se o DropDownList é carregado de forma dinamica, então o ideal é fazer uma requisição AJAX, neste caso o `ActionLink` será muito util.

Neste caso iremos usar a mesma Model e adicionar uma Action/View

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(opcoes);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Opcoes()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var opcoes = new List<Opcao>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
                {
                    opcoes.Add(new Opcao { 
                        ID = i, 
                        Descricao = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                    });
                }
                return View(opcoes);
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden");
        }
    }
}
```

**View - Index**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("Abrir PopUp", "Home", "Opcoes", null, new { 
                @class = "reveal-modal", 
                @data_reveal_id = "modal", 
                @data_reveal_ajax = "true"
            })
            <div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>

            </div>
        </div>      
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(function () {
                $(document).foundation();       
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**View - Opcoes**

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleApp.Opcao>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<p>
    @Html.Label("Opcoes", "Opcoes")
    @Html.DropDownList("Opcoes", Model.Select(item => new SelectListItem {
        Value = item.ID.ToString(),
        Text  = item.Descricao
    }))
</p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">×</a>
```

E por fim um exemplo funcionando no DotNetFiddle (sem ActionLink):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/V0pr0A

Comment: vou tentar. Valeu.